# Why some browsers won't update https page after I deploy changes?

Tags: html, firebase, frontend, browser-cache, firebase-hosting

My problem is that browsers won't show updated page (sometimes) until I press f5 manually

- I have my test site deployed to the Firebase (and by default is https)
- Site is HTML5
- It's not the problem  with this particular site (tried different sites 1.simple html, css site and 2. polymer starter kit with gulp etc.)

In order to resove the problem I've tried to add this code to the HEAD (didn't resolve the problem)

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=0">
```

- When I change anything (let's say add p-tag with random text) and deploy the site again I won't see changes in cases as following:

**FIREFOX:**

*Does NOT show updated page in case:*

- Type site name in a new tab
- Or click on the site from bookmark tab
- I click it 2nd (3rd, ... etc) time on the bookmark bar
- or type manually 2nd (3rd, ... etc) time in a new tab

*Does show updated page in case:*

- If I simply press f5.

**CHROME and Opera**

*Does NOT show updated page in case:*

- Type site name in a new tab
- Or click on the site from bookmark bar

*Does show updated page if:*

- I click it 2nd time on the bookmark bar
- or type manually 2nd time in a new tab
- If I simply press f5

**EDGE browser**

*Works perfectly (how is that even possible??) in case:*

- Type site name in a new tab
- Or click on the site from bookmark bar
- If I simply press f5.

How come that EDGE browser in the only one that update the content of the page, does http-equiv works only with IE, EDGE or what ?

**How do I resolve that problem? How do I make Chrome, Firefox, Opera to look for changes and update it if needed (or just ignore the cache and load it every time without any cache)?**

**Do I need to put some attributes to firebase.json that would look for changes on the page and send updated page to visitors ?
Please help, I spend like 16 hours on research and couldn't find the solution**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your host could have a 1 hour cache delay on the server, that is overriding anything you put in your HEAD. You should check this with Firebase

Alternately, you could run a page reload after page loads for the first time with Javascript, this would get you the same effect as F5.

Something like:

```
location.reload(true);
```

Comment: Thank you Henry, I tried that and it worked (if you remove the script right after execution), but unfortunately, that is not the most optimal way, because who would like to wait watching the page loading twice every time :), but that method gave me some useful information, I didn't know about this reload function before, so, thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your code. If Firebase, you have to tell it to update your DOM when is senses changes. I can't see your code but this is my guess at the problem.
You might be using `ref.once('value',callback(snapshot){})`. This line of code literally only pulls the data once, which is desired sometimes, but not in this case. If that is your problem, you should instead use `ref.on('child_added',callback(snapshot){})` and `ref.on('child_changed',callback(snapshot)(){})`.

Using both of these together will populate the client side data with the Firebase data **and** automatically update it when it changes on the cloud.

Here is the documentation for `.on()`:

- https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html
- https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/once.html

Comment: Thank you for the information, but I saw that documentation already and I didn't understood how to use it, because I'm new to web dev. Anyway problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, for now at least.

If you are facing the same problem, as @Henry24 suggested, just wait an hour and it will do it.
I tried to add this code

```
{
   ...

  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "!{/bower_components,/elements}/**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  } ],

  "headers": [ {
    "source" : "/*.html",
    "headers" : [ {
      "key" : "Cache-Control",
      "value" : "max-age=0"
    } ]
} ]
}
```

to the firebase.json, then `Gulp` then `Firebase deploy`, in order to control cache timing manually, **but it didn't do anything**

All I had to do is wait for an hour and all the changes will appear on the page, because it take an hour for a browser to discard the cache.